# Using Bootstrap carousel with Backbone routes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, carousel

this is my first post.
I'm new to Bootstrap and Backbone and was trying to put it altogether. The problem is when using the image 'carousel' feature, don't know what to do with the route Bootstrap is calling. Here's the typical carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        ....
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="img/imagen0.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/imagen1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

And the Backbone route:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        '' : 'frontPage',
        //Default
        '*actions' : 'defaultAction'
    }
});


    var appRouter = new AppRouter;

    appRouter.on('route:frontPage', function() {
        var indexView = new IndexView();
        indexView.render();
    });

    appRouter.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions) {
        console.log('No route:' + actions);
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
```

Pretty simple. The problem is when the Carousel should start, it uses the #myCarousel link to access the div element, and then Backbone tries to route it. So, I get the default action: No route: myCarousel

Did anyone have this problem? Any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason I was acting on the url with the #myCarousel on it, so it refreshed badly. Thanks anyway

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you found something that worked for you please take some time to post an answer to your question in case anybody else having the same question comes along.

Comment: Well, the problem really was like this: 1.- I started the application without having Bootstrap properly loaded. 2.- When I clicked on the carousel controls with the #myCarousel anchor, instead of activating javascript code, it added the #myCarousel to the page url (unnoticed by me). 3.- Backbone tried to route the URL and found nothing for the #myCarousel anchor. When I was refreshing the page, I didn't noticed I was doing it over the wrong URL. Silly mistake from programming at late hours. Ensured bootstrap was loaded correctly and the URL was also right and everything worked fine.